# Django UnitTesting: 'AnonymousUser' object has no attribute

Tags: django, unit-testing

I have the following code:

```
class CampaignModelTests(TestCase):

    # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/testing/advanced/

    def setUp(self):
        # create some test campaigns
        shop = Shop.objects.create(name='Test Shop')
        self.factory = RequestFactory()
        self.user = User.objects.create(shop_username='testuser', shop=shop)
        self.merchant = User.objects.create(username='merchant', password='merchant123', is_merchant=True, shop=shop)
        self.campaign = Campaign.objects.create(name='Test Campaign', shop=shop)

    def test_campaign_creation(self):
        request = self.factory.get(reverse('create-campaign'), {
            'name': 'Test Campaign -1',
            'shop': Shop(name='Test Shop').sid
        })
        request.user = self.merchant
        print('request.user: ', request.user.is_merchant)
        response = CampaignCreate.as_view()(request)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
```

And I am getting the following error:

```
return request.user.is_merchant or request.user.is_superuser
AttributeError: 'AnonymousUser' object has no attribute 'is_merchant'
```

I have tried using `self.client` as well but still the same error.

```
self.client.force_login(self.merchant)

# send a request to the view
response = self.client.post(reverse('create-campaign'), {
     'name': 'Test Campaign -1',
     'shop': Shop(name='Test Shop').sid
})
self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
```

Comment: you might need to call force_authenticate(request, user=user)
https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/testing/

Comment: yes. you are right. It got fixed after I add that